# @angular/forms/index"' has no exported mng 'FormsModule'

Tags: angular

I'm totally new to Angular 2 and I'm getting this error when trying to import FormsModule on my app.module.ts file.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

This is the dependencies on my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
"es6-shim": "0.35.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"systemjs": "0.19.26",
"zone.js": "0.6.12"
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line of package.json:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0"
```

update to:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.3.0"
```

run again:

```
npm install
```

problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

update dependencies to

```
 "dependencies": {
     "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
     "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
     "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
     "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
     "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
     "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
     "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
     "core-js": "^2.4.1",
     "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
     "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
     "systemjs": "0.19.27",
     "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
     "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
     "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"   },
```

Run again:

npm install